# flask-apispec not populating kwargs with values from GET query (implementation of example code from documentation)

Tags: python, flask, webargs, flask-apispec

I am using `flask-apispec` with `webargs` to define the types of a simple API. I have produced a minimal example, below, that reproduces the issue, which is that the `kwargs` object is empty.

Server code:

```
import flask
from flask_apispec import use_kwargs
from webargs import fields

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/pets', methods=["GET"])
@use_kwargs({'species': fields.Str()})
def list_pets(**kwargs):
    assert False, kwargs  # NO DATA HERE


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Simple client script:

```
import requests
requests.get("http://localhost:5000/pets", params={"species": "cat"})
```

Why is the `kwargs` dict empty? I don't see how the above is at all different from the example in the flask-apispec documentation.

Comment: Very strange. I did get `use_kwargs` from webargs to work. flask-apispec's `use_kwargs` function is doing *something* since `print(list_pets.__apispec__['args'][0].options)` gives something back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and suffered a little with the documentation.

Referencing [webargs docs](https://webargs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (that is what I understood `flask-apispec` uses under the hood) I found some examples and was able to implement it.

The `location` parameter is what was missing.
In your example it would be:

```py
@app.route('/pets', methods=["GET"])
@use_kwargs({'species': fields.Str()}, location="query")
def list_pets(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs) # Now "species" should be here if sent through the query
```

I'm using `flask-apispec v0.11.1`, which installed `webargs v8.1.0` on my system.